# Convert string to currency format without casting to numerical value first

Tags: vb.net

This code -

```
Convert.ToDecimal("28.9100000000000000").ToString("c")
```

will convert a string containing a decimal value to a nicely formatted currency value. Is there anyway to do this without first converting the string value to a decimal?

Comment: What precision do you want to keep? Do you want the currency symbol to be culture sensitive?

Comment: I'm happy with the defaults for the precision and currency symbol, I was suspicious that I had missed a really obvious method somewhere that would allow me to format the string without doing the conversion first.

Comment: Nope, you missed nothing. The defaults would of course depend on the current thread and UI thread cultures.

Comment: Thanks, that's put my mind at rest!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to preserve culture specific currency attributes (currency symbol, separators and precision), your current approach looks like the best one.

If you know the precision and don't care about cultures, you can do some simple string manipulation:

```
 "$" & myString.Substring(0, myString.IndexOf(".") + 3)
```

Comment: +1 @ipr101 you really should just use the approach in your question. There's nothing wrong with it, and it has many advantages. It's more readable, it throws an exception if your input string is not numerical, it respects the users' Control Panel choices for currency formatting, it's regionally aware...

Answer (score 4):

A simple method that I use:

```
MoneyString = string.format("{0:C}",DecimalValue)
```

Comment: I found this answer useful - although the question seemed to be asking for a solution which didn't involve using a decimal.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
decimalString = "28.910000000000000000"
currencyString = "$" + decimalString.SubString(0, decimalString.IndexOf('.') + 3)
```

Of course, if you're going to do this you also need to worry about locale settings.  Probably just as easy to do the numeric conversion, and let the framework do the formatting for you.